# Laravel Policy not being called

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I am using Laravel 10. and I am using the Spaite package for the role permissions.

Now, I have created Policy for Profession module that only can access by admin role.
I registered the Policy in AuthServiceProvider but it's not being called.

```php
use App\Models\Profession;
use App\Policies\ProfessionPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Profession::class => ProfessionPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

I am missing something to register it. I also follow the Laravel docs for the same. but it's not working at all. :|

Comment: you register policy is ok.. can you show your ProfessionPolicy code.. and where you call it

Comment: Just for case, execute `composer du` to reload classes. After such a change I used to execute chained `composer du && php artisan optimize:clear`.

Comment: @UmerFayyaz, there just Policies functions, like viewAny() and so on ..
even I tried to `dd` in the Policy but it was not going there

Answer (score 0):

In my test it only works by changing the class that extends

```
// use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when trying to check if a particular user has an admin role or not. Here is my code:

UserPolicy.phph

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Users\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use JCKCon\Enums\UsersRoles;

class UserPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function isAdmin(User $user): bool
    {
        
        return $user->getRoleNames()[0] === UsersRoles::ADMIN->value;
    }
}
```

However I was able to get to work by doing this in the AuthServiceProvider boot method.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

use App\Models\Users\User;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // Add this section of code and everything should work perfectly
        foreach ($this->policies as $model => $policy) {
            $definedPolicies = get_class_methods($policy);

            foreach ($definedPolicies as $method) {
                Gate::define($method, [$policy, $method]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For me with the above peice of code:

```php
foreach ($this->policies as $model => $policy) {
    $definedPolicies = get_class_methods($policy);

    foreach ($definedPolicies as $method) {
        Gate::define($method, [$policy, $method]);
    }
}
```

using the Gate::check method like this solve my problem:

```php
public function saveSettings(): SettingsHandler
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            if (!Gate::check("isAdmin")) {
                return $this->raise(APIResponseMessages::RES_UNAUTHORIZED->value, null, APIResponseCodes::UNAUTHORIZED->value);
            }

            $params = $this->request->all(["name", "desc", "about", "email", "phone_number", "line_address", "facebook_handle", "twitter_handle", "whatsapp_handle", "instagram_handle", "linkedin_handle"]);

            if (!($Settings = Modules::Settings()->add($params))) {
                DB::rollBack();
                DB::commit();

                return $this->raise(APIResponseMessages::DB_ERROR->value, null, APIResponseCodes::SERVER_ERR->value);
            }

            /* process image upload */
            if (!empty($this->request->file("site_logo"))) {
                if (!($logoPath = $this->processSiteLogoUpload())) {
                    return $this->raise(APIResponseMessages::UPL_ERR->value, null, APIResponseCodes::SERVER_ERR->value);
                }

                if (!Modules::Settings()->update($Settings->site_id, ["logo" => $logoPath])) {
                    DB::rollBack();
                    DB::commit();

                    return $this->raise(APIResponseMessages::DB_ERROR->value, null, APIResponseCodes::SERVER_ERR->value);
                }
            }

            /* fetch updated settings values from storage. */
            $Settings = Modules::Settings()->get($Settings->site_id);

            //-----------------------------------------------------

            /** Request response data */
            $responseMessage = "Success, application settings saved successfully!";
            $response["type"] = "settings";
            $response["body"] = $Settings;
            $responseCode = Modules::Settings()->hasSettings() ? 200 : 201;

            DB::commit();

            return $this->response($response, $responseMessage, $responseCode);
        } catch (Exception $th) {
            Log::error($th->getMessage(), ["Line" => $th->getLine(), "file" => $th->getFile()]);

            DB::rollBack();
            DB::commit();

            return $this->raise();
        }
    }
```

I help this helps you get moving.